# Loading a series of PNGs as a texture

Tags: xna, textures

If I have a series of PNGs that I'd like to use as a single animated texture, would I be able to use them as they are, or would I first need to convert them to a different format, like a single TGA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are programs helping you in this task. I personally use [Zwoptex](http://zwopple.com/zwoptex/).
Basically you load all your pngs, it arranges them (translating and rotating each sprite) into a bigger image (you decide the size) called texture atlas. You can then export the atlas with a xml file containing the coordinates of each single sprite in the atlas.

Comment: I'd just like to add: check out sprite sheet packer, which is an open source alternative. But yeah using a texture atlas is definitely the way to go, its much more efficient than using separate files for each frame. (bit more info in my answer here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27200/how-are-buttons-made-to-be-clicked/27206#27206)

Comment: ImageMagick is a command line utility that is capable of combining images in this manner.

Comment: TexturePacker is my favorite, but regardless note that Zwoptex and TexturePacker are Mac software, Sprite Sheet Packer is Windows, and ImageMagick is platform agnostic.